# How to post an answer to a closed question?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions, unanswered-questions

Question is [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39339/identification-of-an-insect-found-in-south-india), I commented my answer to it,

But I want to post my answer in **Answer box**, Due to **closed** status, I can't do anything.

Answer (score 7):

It has to be re-opened first. I see the question image has been updated and I vote to re-open. Four other users need to vote-to-re-open and then you're good to go.

You can delete your answer-in-comment disguise and post it as answer instead once the question is re-opened.

Thanks for bringing this up here.